# ObjectiveC MKMapView does not load some locations when WIFI is on

Tags: objective-c, iphone, mkmapview

I have a map view that does not always load locations (it seems like the more remote locations i.e. not main cities), only the grid and pin is shown but no map, and I see it is only when i am on the WIFI. The wifi appears to be solid, is this a known problem and is it resolvable? I've put my code in below although as i say it works for most locations, 100% on 3g less so on WIFI. The mapView is inside a webView

```
    self.mapView.scrollEnabled = true;
    self.mapView.zoomEnabled = true;

    MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.003, 0.003);
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-26.204029, 28.039171), span);

    [_mapView setRegion: region];

    MapAnnotation *annotation = [[[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinates: region.center
                                                                      title: @""   
                                                                 subTitle: @""] autorelease];

    [self.mapView addAnnotation: annotation];
```

Comment: Do you actually have a connection when not in WiFi? If not, then the map remains empty because MapKit cannot load its contents. So exactly what you describe. BTW, your subject line is a bit misleading and this is not related to xcode.

Comment: to clarify: when in 3G it works when using wifi it doesn't always load (loads some not others . I am also editing the original post as the map view is inside a web view which might have an impact